# Why doesn't localStorage.setItem work outside of componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm working on a very small React app and I need some help understanding why the following code works:

```
componentDidMount() {
 localStorage.setItem('lists', JSON.stringify(this.state.lists))
}
```

But if I try to put the same functionality into my own method on the component to trigger saving on a button press, it does nothing:

```
saveData() {
 localStorage.setItem('lists', JSON.stringify(this.state.lists))
}
```

I used an alert to test if the saveData() method got called properly and it was fine; so why didn't the localStorage code work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `saveData` bound to the context in the `constructor()`?

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.lists));`

Comment: `console.log(localStorage.getItem('lists');`

Comment: Yup, I wasn't binding 'this' nor using ES6 syntax. D'oh. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use arrow function es6 new syntax of writing function

```
saveData = () => {
 localStorage.setItem('lists', JSON.stringify(this.state.lists))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've chosen to just add a bind in the constructor to follow the style of this app (it's not mine) but your answer made me realise what was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: what was your mistake? im kinda running into the same problem @LukeWheeler

Comment: Because I wasn't using ES6 arrow function syntax (you don't need to bind 'this' in constructor when using arrow functions). I followed the style of the code already there and forgot to add a bind.